# Adding CSS to each page on WordPress

Tags: performance, php, css, iteration, wordpress

I just started to use WordPress to start building a website, but as I need to use the `get_header()` function to retrieve the `<head>` content and I have a very large project, I wanted to put a CSS file depending on the page that is being displayed. After a few tries I came up with a solution, but I think that I can do it in a better way and I need your help to optimize it.

I'd like my code to be \$O(1)\$ not \$O(n)\$.

Here is my PHP snippet that goes into the functions.php file:

```
function website_files_per_page() {
    $pagelist = get_pages();
    $index = sizeof($pagelist);
    while ($index --) {
        $pagename = $pagelist[$index]->post_name;
        if (is_page($pagename)){
            $styleName = "website_".$pagename."_styles";
            $styleDir = get_theme_file_uri("/style/".$pagename.".css");
            wp_enqueue_style($styleName, $styleDir);
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action("wp_print_styles", "website_files_per_page");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A simpler approach to add the style can be used

Per your request:

> I'd like my code to be \$O(1)\$ not \$O(n)\$.

I haven’t tested this but based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628266/1575353) using [`global $post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Inside_the_Loop_variables) and `$post->page_title` to set `$pagename` should allow for elimination for the `while` loop.

```
function website_files_per_page() {
    global $post;
    $pagename = $post->post_title;
    if (!$pagename) {
        return; //no page name
    }
    $styleName = "website_".$pagename."_styles";
    $styleDir = get_theme_file_uri("/style/".$pagename.".css");
    wp_enqueue_style($styleName, $styleDir);
}
add_action("wp_print_styles", "website_files_per_page");
```

That would allow the code to run in \$O(1)\$ time instead of \$O(n)\$.

## PHP can parse variables in double quoted strings

Per the [PHP documentation for Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> ##### [Simple syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)
>
> If a dollar sign (`$`) is encountered, the parser will
> greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable
> name. Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify
> the end of the name.

Thus a line like this:

> ```
>        $styleName = "website_".$pagename."_styles";
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
        $styleName = "website_{$pagename}_styles";
```

## PHP can handle the iteration

If the suggestion to use `$post` doesn’t work, you may be able to change the `while` loop to a [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach). [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach) provides an easy way to iterate over arrays:

```
foreach ($pagelist as $post) {
    $pagename = $post->post_name;
    if (is_page($pagename)) {
        ...
```

With this approach there is no need to initialize and update a counter (e.g. `$index`) to dereference elements in the array.

If there was a need to access the index/counter variable then the second syntax can be used for that:

```
foreach ($pagelist as $index => $post) {
```

Comment: This works pretty awesome and does what I wanted, reduce the time to O(1). Thanks!